# Partial zeta curlicues

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I asked a question at MSE and [Raymond Manzoni](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21783/raymond-manzoni) provided an excellent [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805396/simpler-zeta-zeros/815480#815480) that included these visuals:

[image]
[image]

I made a very basic attempt at recreation with

```
y = 10000; ListLinePlot[Table[{Im[E^(-I y Log[k])/Sqrt[k]], Re[E^(-I y  
Log[k])/Sqrt[k]]}, {k, 1, Round[Sqrt[10000]]}]]
```

but a very messy plot resulted. I tried various parametric plots, but was equally disappointed with the results. Could someone please point me in the right direction to achieve the curlicues (that were apparently applet-generated) in the answer listed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to define partial sums (I will use Simon's definition in the comments which is faster than my older one):

```
Manzoni[n_, y_] := Transpose@{Re@#, Im@#} &@Accumulate[Range[n]^-(.5 + y I)]
```

The thing worth attention here is `1/k^(.5 + I y)` - meaning 0.5 which makes it automatically numeric **before** the sum is taken. If you would keep `1/2` and wrap `N[...]` outside it would be much slower.

```
ListLinePlot[Manzoni[3000, 10000], Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
                  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.7]]]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Manzoni[4000, 10000], Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Opacity[.2]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-.3398, -.339}, {-.0378, -.0365}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

From pure artistic point of view I think a spline can make it real pretty, perhaps even tattoo-ready ;-)

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[Manzoni[3000, 10000]]]
```

[image]

Other parameters:

```
Graphics[BSplineCurve[Manzoni[5000, 20000]]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is incredible! Thank you so much for writing this - I hope this answer gets the attention it deserves!!

Comment: You could use something like `data = Transpose@{Re@#, Im@#} &@ Accumulate[Range[3000]^-(0.5 + 10000 I)];` to calculate the data

Comment: +1 @SimonWoods - much better of course - thank you - I updated the post with your definition.

Comment: +1. BTW I think there is an L-system generating a similar pattern, but I failed to find the exact name.